# How do I put margin between div in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put some 5px margin between box I created, and this margin should be constant, if I resize the browser window.

My html is like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div style="height: 121px; background-color: orange; width:100%;">
                    <label>Box 1</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div style="height: 121px;background-color: wheat; width:100%;">
                    <label>Box 2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div style="height: 121px;background-color: beige ;width:100%;">
                    <label>Box 3</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div style="height: 121px;background-color: chocolate; width:100%;">
                    <label>Box 4</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
```

So in above html I used div with background colors. And I want to put some margin between them.

Comment: Are you referring that they do not have padding when resized smaller between top/bottom divs?

Comment: Hi, i want margin same if i resize browsers, let's say if u put margin between box 5 px, then it should be same, if i resize

Comment: `padding-*` should do the trick. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp . Add padding and remove custom height.

Comment: i know, but padding is not working here :(

Comment: added an answer to help you

Answer (score 9):

Following the cannonical way to add margin and padding in Bootstrap, you can do this.

Classes format:

- `{property}{sides}-{size}` for xs
- `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` for sm, md, lg, and xl.

Where `property` is one of:

- m - for classes that set margin
- p - for classes that set padding

Where `sides` is one of:

- t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
- b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
- l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
- r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
- x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
- y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
- blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

Where `size` is one of:

- 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
- 1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
- 2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
- 3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
- 4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
- 5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3

**Examples**

1. Padding * 1.5 in all sides: `<div class="p-4">`
2. Margin default on top: `<div class="mt-3">`
3. Padding * 0.25 on left and right: `<div class="px-1">`

*More info at their page, under Utilities > Spacing: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/*

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your code in [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is that columns (`<div class="col-*"></div>`) have custom padding. There will always be equal width between your divs, but not always equal height (unless you start adding bootstrap rows which is handled the same way vertically and columns are horizontally with padding).

To solve this problem in your case you just need to add padding to your divs. [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/SiStiFFITU)

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2  col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <div style="background-color: orange;">
                <label>Box 1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <div style="background-color: wheat; ">
                <label>Box 2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <div style="background-color: beige; ">
                <label>Box 3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <div style="background-color: chocolate;">
                <label>Box 4</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use padding-right? and first box has large width then others :(

Comment: I fixed it for you, the first div had `col-md-3` while the others were `col-md-2 `, And to answer why not use padding right; it is because that has to do with the width, which bootstrap's CSS handles. I also removed width:100%, because it is not necessary,

Comment: why mix style on the HTML code when you can do that with the bootstrap solution for that?

Comment: @Natacha, this post is 6 years old. It may need to be updated feel free to do so!

Answer (score 2):

Why not using css with `margin-bottom:5px;` ?

```css
.col-xs-12{
    margin-bottom: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div style="height: 121px; background-color: orange; width:100%;">
                <label>Box 1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div style="height: 121px;background-color: wheat; width:100%;">
                <label>Box 2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div style="height: 121px;background-color: beige ;width:100%;">
                <label>Box 3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div style="height: 121px;background-color: chocolate; width:100%;">
                <label>Box 4</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because that's not bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I tried just putting some breaks in. Is this what you were looking for?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div style="height: 121px; background-color: orange; width:100%;">
        <label>Box 1</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div style="height: 121px;background-color: wheat; width:100%;">
        <label>Box 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div style="height: 121px;background-color: beige ;width:100%;">
        <label>Box 3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div style="height: 121px;background-color: chocolate; width:100%;">
        <label>Box 4</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you looking for like a border type thing?

Comment: Looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/A4qB2/2/ ? I didn't import bootstrap, sorry, but if you add padding to the parents, it'll work like margin on the children and give you that space between the colors while working with border-box + 100% width.

Comment: what are the best solution, i think my question is very simple :(

Comment: Sorry. I was confused what it was you were looking for.